# C# outlook interop fetching emails is slow

Tags: c#

I have approx 10000 emails in an outlook folder.
I  am trying to fetch emails from this folder using outlook interop dll in c# code where email item must be sent between provided start and end date. Following is the code i am using:

```
var app = Outlook.Application();
_NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI") ;
var inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
var folder = inbox.Folders["FolderName" ] ;
var mailItems = folder.Items.Cast<MailItem>().
    Where(x=>x.sentOn>=startDate && x.sentOn < endDate).OrderBy(x=>x.ReceivedTime).ToList();
// email parsing logic...
```

This code works but its very slow. How do i improve its performance?

Comment: fetching 10 000 emails is the problem. why so many?

Comment: @Seabizkit - thats the requirement.

Comment: saying the requirement is the requirement.... OK then... I find that this requirement is unrealistic and possible not possible, would gladly be proven wrong, but with some understanding of what you asking the system to do i find it hard to believe that you will find a performant way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1) You could move the OrderBy method after the ToList (or remove it altogether). It's one less operation that the mail server has deal with, and it's likely be much faster to order the data in code.

2) You could create your own version of the MailItem model which only contains the properties that you need. That may reduce the amount of information that you're requesting.

Hope this helps.

** Edit

3) The Restrict() extension would let you filter the results before the cast, see the example below:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = null;
try
{
    application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");fsdf

    var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt");
    var endDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt");

    var ns = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    var inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    var folder = inbox;
    var filter = $"[sentOn] > '{startDate}' And [sentOn] < '{endDate}'";

    var mailItems = folder.Items.Restrict(filter);

    foreach (MailItem item in mailItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: i tired your both the suggestions. It just resulted in overall improvement of 1 sec. I think its taking a performance hit as its executing cast() on all the email items post which its filtering email items. Isn't there a way I can filter first and then do a cast.

Comment: I'd expect your 1 and 2 to execute on the client anyway: yes, these are the sort of things that e.g. Entity Framework will offload to the server, by modifying the SQL it generates, but I don't think Office Interop can do this. There is a version of 2, though: [Items.SetColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._items.setcolumns.aspx) which might be worth trying. And I agree Restrict() might help.

Comment: @bower - Thanks approach 3 works perfectly and now my code runs in just 1 sec. Above code posted by you needs a slight correction. DateTime object [startDate/endDate] must be formatted in "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt" format. Otherwise the filtered records count is 0. Please update the correct format in the answer you posted. :-)